# Debug unstable Apache server under Debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, memory, memory-usage

Since yesterday my Apache server that runs on a Debian machine runs very unstable. Sometiems my websites load and sometimes not. I think it has to do with the memory since my Apache log is full of  Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 4480 bytes). I also attached a screenshot of the memory graph.[image]

A server restart resolves the problem temporarily. I looked at the processes that are using memory but the biggest one is MySQL with 6.5%.

Where else can  look for the problem?

Edit: I did a free -m right after rebooting and one about 2 hours later. I think the trend is visible:

```
root@xxx:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4016        731       3284          0         80        200
-/+ buffers/cache:        449       3566
Swap:          459          0        459

root@xxx:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4016       2466       1550          0         92        473
-/+ buffers/cache:       1900       2115
Swap:          459          0        459
```

Comment: free -m would be nice to see. A ps xua | grep httpd (or apache2) would be good too, so we can see the amount of memory apache is using.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I added the free -m

Answer (score 1):

You probably have lots and lots of apache processes running. Issue a `ps ax | grep apache2 | wc -l` to see how much.

If your `KeepAliveTimeout` parameter is too big (like the default), someone can connect to you, let the connection linger, and eat up all your resources.

I usually use `KeepAliveTimeout 5`, so when nothign gets back in 5 seconds, Apache can drop the connection.

Check the `MaxConnectionsPerChild` too. If they are unlimited, a memory leak will eat up all your memory. Use something nice, like 10000 or 50000.

Take a look on the loaded modules too. You may have a couple of unused modules, and they take a little memory on each process instance. Although the amount is small, it sums up very quick.

Lastly, take a look on your logs. See if there's anything strange on the logs. You can found that your server is suffering an attack, or someone installed a failing library, or things like that.

Comment: ps ax | grep apache2 | wc -l returns: 29

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. But the problem continues. What I don't understand is that, if  list all active processes I the memory usage does not sum up to such a high usage. Who or what is using my memory?

Comment: `ps aux --sort -rss` will show the sorted memory usage.

Comment: I give you an upvote because I think that my problem has many causes and solutions. In my case it was differente but your answere is still valuable for people searching this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the MaxRequestsPerChild parameter if it's 0 try to change it to value more like 1000 (depends on traffic). Out of memory info suggest that you use PHP, check the memory_limit and max_execution_time values in your php.ini, maybe you should increase/decrease the time/memory. Please provide more info about the config of Apache/PHP and application.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the problem was a big mail queue. Deleting the queue solved the problem.

Comment: Good to hear!
We didn't knew that you had a mail and http server on the same host. It would make a lot of difference if you mentioned that, but it's good to know you solved the problem!